# What does the content between <span> tags do in .webpart files?

Tags: html, user-interface, sharepoint

I'm working with .webpart files. I have one .webpart that has `span` tags within `property`. I'm wondering if the content within `span` tags would show up in the UI? Can I delete all the `span` tags without any impact?An example is shown below:

```
    <property name="ViewFlag" type="string" />
        <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
        <property name="ListName" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="SummaryLinkStore" type="string">

&lt;div title="_sersion" id="_3"&gt;
      &lt;div title="_links"&gt;
        &lt;div title="_link"&gt;
          &lt;span title="_title"&gt;Frequently Asked Ops &lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_order"&gt;1&lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_begincolumn"&gt;True&lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_linkurl"&gt;
            &lt;a href="/EnglishToolkit/2.0 Pre Go-Live/2.6 Launch FAQs/2.6 loySpanish.pdf"&gt;/English/lobal/Documents/HR Communication/2.0 Pre/2.6 Launch FAQs/2.6 ployee_FAQs_Global_Spanish.pdf&lt;/a&gt;
          &lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_style"&gt;Default&lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_openinnindow"&gt;True&lt;/span&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;div title="_link"&gt;
          &lt;span title="_title"&gt;HR Maps&lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_order"&gt;2&lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_begincolumn"&gt;False&lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_linkurl"&gt;
            &lt;a href="global/Documents/HR Process Maps"&gt;/English/Documents/HR Process Maps&lt;/a&gt;
          &lt;/span&gt;
          &lt;span title="_style"&gt;substring-before-last&lt;/span&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
```

Thank you very much and I'm looking forward to your reply!

Comment: Its Better to write your code so people can copy your text and run it

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I just corrected it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It does the same as in regular HTML pages.

The html code is shown "somewhere". Either in the view of this webpart while viewing it in Sharepoint or another compatible viewer, *or* in another webpart's view.

Your screenshot reveals some of its content. But you maybe did not notice, that, before the very first `<div title="_sersion" id="_3">` in your image there is an *opening* property tag. The closing one would be somewhere outside of the contents the screenshot shows. Hence this `SummaryLinkStore` property's content is all the html and is probably shown somewhere else.

So it depends on your personal judgement if the content is needed or not. Which is why your question is a bit of misleading in the first place, and depends on opinion. According to the guidelines questions on opinions should not be asked.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your quick reply! Sorry that I don't know it is a guideline question. Now I know that the content within `span` would show (and we'll need to keep the content). But I'm still wondering if I can delete all the <span> tags, leaving the content as it is? Would it change anything?

Comment: You're welcome. :) You can change the tags as you would in a normal html page. It just would change the way the content is presented at the particular place. As you have not presented too much information about the eco system you're using it's hard to guess where and when it is shown. But if it's there, chances are big that it is shown. *And* it's not my guideline but as I am myself new to this site I have recently regarded downvotings on opinionated questions and even some getting "closed" by some of the admins.

Comment: At least make a backup of your files and if one day you notice where the content is shown, you could easily change it back to how it was, if you don't like the way it looks then.

Comment: Thank you! Actually we received the .webpart file from our client. We'll confirm with them whether we should keep tag or not. Thank you :)